# Android Geocoder is not working when app is installed on a Device but is working fine on the Emulator

Tags: android, firebase, google-geocoder

PLEASE BEAR WITH ME AND READ THE STATEMENT AND IF ANY ADDITIONAL INFO IS NEEDED COMMENT AND I'LL PROVIDE IT , I'M NEW TO THIS AND LEARNING HOW TO ASK QUESTIONS .

I recently Started working on my College Minor Project . A few Days Back Geocoder was working Properly when the App was being installed on my Phone but suddenly It's stopped working .The Only new Lines which I saw in my Log are These . Can Someone Please tell me what I Did Wrong as I didn't change any Line of Code and everything is working fine on the Emulator .
PS: If any additional Info is needed I'll try to provide it ASAP.

```
2020-12-15 18:37:16.733 12172-12218/com.example.raktdaan W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lu@e1c8911
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1759)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1786)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:751)
    at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204514081@20.45.14 (120400-0):1)
    at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204514081@20.45.14 (120400-0):2)
    at lv.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204514081@20.45.14 (120400-0):9)
    at lf.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204514081@20.45.14 (120400-0):3)
    at ef.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204514081@20.45.14 (120400-0):3)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at iy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204514081@20.45.14 (120400-0):5)
```

My Code to get user Location is :

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER , 1 , 1 , locationListener ) ;
locationListener = location -> {
        Geocoder geoLoc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addList = geoLoc.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (addList != null && addList.size() > 0) {
                loc = addList.get(0).getLocality();
                textLocation.setText(loc);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(registration.this, "Unable to Access Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
```

Same Code Runs Flawlessly on the Android Studio Emulator but not working when the App is Installed on the Device .

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: According to this [comment on github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1662#issuecomment-743265157), it is not a fatal error, it's just a logcat warning, and the firebase team is working to fix it.

Comment: Yes, Thank you @jon and frank...... After a lot of research I found that out and the problem with my Geocoder was that LocationListener wasn't working (I still don't know why), but I replaced it with FusedLocationProvider and everything was normal again. But this error appeared at the same time LocationListener stopped working, as this was first unsupervised project and I'm still a rookie, I got panicked and asked a question here. That's a lot anyway for your time.